# Is there any way to remove auto-select after autocomplete on VS-code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

as the title says I'm looking for a way to remove the autoselect code after autocomplete. Currently, the only way to remove the autoselected line is either pressing ESC key or clicking anywhere else. And it's currently giving me issues because it's quite annoying.

I've been searching for a solution for about 3 days and it's either I'm doing it wrong or I don't really know what the issue exactly is... Here's a picture of my issue

[image: Picture of the issue]

As you see in the picture, the code is autoselected/highlighted right after autocomplete and as said I really need help because it's turning annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen in non-Dart files?

Answer (score 7):

Set `Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` to false, in text editor > suggestions